# How to scale down pixbuf image without losing quality?

Tags: python, cairo, pixbuf

I have a pixbuf image and I want to save it to pdf using cairo. Because the pixbuf is too large, I want to scale it down. I use `scale_simple` method. But, the scaled result became blur.  Below is the screenshot I take. The real image is on the right and on the left is image from pdf [image: blur]

Do you know how to scale down pixbuf without losing its quality? Below is just my sample code.

```
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf, Gdk
import cairo

class gui():
    def __init__(self):
        pix = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file('tux2.png')
        pix = pix.scale_simple(pix.get_width() / 3, pix.get_height() / 3, GdkPixbuf.InterpType.HYPER)
        ps = cairo.PDFSurface('pix.pdf', 500, 500)
        cr = cairo.Context(ps)
        Gdk.cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pix, 0, 0)
        cr.paint()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui()
```

Comment: When you scale a (bitmapped) image down, unless you're simultaneously increasing its dpi, you're _always_ losing quality. There's no way around that. A 200x200 image only has 4/9ths the information of a 300x300 image, and you can't throw away 55% of your information without losing quality. Averaging, blurring, dithering, and other techniques are attempts to make the loss less visible; they all have obvious side effects, but not using them has even more obvious side effects.

Comment: I believe the question is exactly about increasing dpi, as output is PDF, essentially a vector format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not scale the pixbuf at all.

Instead you should scale the object (pixbuf as is).

It will look something like this:

```
cr.save()
cr.scale(scale_xy, scale_xy)
cr.xxx_place_image(...)
cr.restore()
```

Comment: np. to add a caveat, say your user dumped a 80Kx80K 16-bits-per-channel rgba image, that will result in a huge pdf, in that case you may want to prescale raster image :)

Answer (score 0):

What about recreating this particular image using PDF commands? It's vector format and you may design similar image in svg and import it.Image scaling is a fatal process of loosing actual color data, cause approximation takes place. Use advanced scaling algorithm, Lanczos filtering for example.